# How to convert underline text to outline in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I´m preparing a 24 pages manual InDesign file to send to the commercial printer service. When I convert some underline texto to outline, the underline disappears. Same thing with bullets. Is there a solution to this conflict?

Comment: Why are you outlining the text at all? What will you do if you need to change something?

Answer (score 3):

There's an answer on the Adobe Forum [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/326617) - which basically says to highlight the text first.

However ask yourself this, do you really need to outline the fonts?  If you supply the artwork in PDF to your printer, you shouldn't need to do this at all.

There's an article [here](https://indesignsecrets.com/outlining-fonts-is-it-necessary.php) on the subject which might interest you.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and observations. Actually, the printer ask me to outline the text.

Comment: I'm trying to convert to outline in order to add effects to just portions of the text, highlighting the text doesn't work. And the forum link you provide links to a nothing page.